# Server and Java Applet: Connecting Socket

Tags: sockets

I have a java applet recently stopped working after the server is updated, more specifically:
1. The server is updated from Sun, running Solaris 9, 32 bit. (installed in 2005) to CentOS 5, (linux) on 64 bit.
2. The applet has two major classes 1) collect.class: collects data from a canvas 2) server.class: listens to collect.class through a PORT and acts accordingly;

but the applet got stuck and I check the start_server.sh (which produces a report nohup.out) there is a line

```
Exception creating server socket: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

This is weird, because PORT = 9999 which collect.class uses with no problem.  How comes the problem happens only in server.class  (who listens to collet.class).

Please help!

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I.IN COLLECT.JAVA:
There is a canvas with grid on it, the user draw some area on the grid and click "Submit".
-> The MineCanvas.submit() is triggered -> The value of the area is computed by MineCanvas.ComputeGridValue() -> then Collect.cleintSend (stuck here)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Collect extends Applet {

...
public static final int PORT = 8888;
...

public boolean action(Event e, Object arg) {
...
        if (arg.equals("Submit")) {
        if (action(null, "Update Grid")) {
            minecanvas.Submit();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
...
public void clientSend(){ 
    s = new Socket(this.getCodeBase().getHost(), PORT);
        in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());}
            out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            listener = new SolutionListener(in, minecanvas);}
        minecanvas.mode = MineCanvas.SUBMITTING;
    minecanvas.repaint();


    int n = 1;
    out.writeBytes(minecanvas.gridh + "\n" + minecanvas.gridw + "\n");

    for (int h = 0; h < minecanvas.gridh; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < minecanvas.gridw; w++) {
            out.writeBytes(n + " " + minecanvas.AllCells[w][h].net + "\n");
            n++;
        }
    }
    out.writeBytes("done\n");

        s = null;
        in = null;
    out = null;


}
}

class MineCanvas extends Canvas {
...
public int gridw = 0;                       // number of grid squares width-ly

public int gridh = 0;                       // number of grid squares height-ly

public GridCell[][] AllCells;                   // array of grid cells comprising the grid
...

// compute values for minecanvas 
public void ComputeGridValue() {...}    


public void Submit() {
    ComputeGridValue();
    parent.clientSend();
}

    ...

}
...

}
```

II. SERVER.JAVA

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server extends Thread {
private OPM_Server opm; // this is the corresponding server for collect
...
public Server() {
    ...
    opm = new OPM_Server();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server();
}
}

...
// OPM: correspond to Collect
class OPM_Server extends Thread {
public final static int DEFAULT_PORT = 8888;
protected int port;
protected ServerSocket listen_socket;

public static void fail(Exception e, String msg) {
    System.err.println(msg + ": " + e);
    System.exit(1);
}

public OPM_Server() {
    this.port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    try { listen_socket = new ServerSocket(port); }
    catch (IOException e){ fail(e, "Exception creating server socket");}
    System.out.println("Server: listening on port " + port);
    this.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("I got to before ServerSocket");
            Socket client_socket = listen_socket.accept();
            OPM_Connection c = new OPM_Connection(client_socket);
            }
        }
    catch (IOException e) {fail(e, "Exception while listening for connections");}
}
}
...
class OPM_Connection extends Thread {
protected Socket client;
protected BufferedReader in;
protected DataOutputStream out;
File mine_data = new File("mine_data");  // output file data 
FileOutputStream file_stream;
DataOutputStream file_out;

public OPM_Connection(Socket client_socket) {
    client = client_socket;
    try {

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
        ;
        System.err.println("Exception while getting socket stream: "
                + e.toString());
        return;
    }
    this.start();
}

public void run() {
    ...

    file_stream = new FileOutputStream(mine_data);
    file_out = new DataOutputStream(file_stream);
    ...// write to mine data

    file_out = null;
    if (inputGood == true) {
        System.out.println(pid + "> ---Got all info from client");
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process Aproc = null;
        Process Bproc = null;
        int returnVal = -1;
        try {
            Aproc = r.exec("runOPM");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            inputGood = false;
            System.out.println(pid + "> runOPM didn't exec");
        }
        try {
            returnVal = Aproc.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            inputGood = false;
            System.out.println(pid + "> runOPM didn't return");
        }
        System.out.println(pid + "> ---All execing done");

        File report = new File("mine_report");
        FileInputStream report_stream = null;
        ... 
        // create a mine report

        System.out.println(pid + "> ---Done sending data back to client");
    }
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    }
    ;
    System.out.println(pid + "> EXITING THREAD");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Exception creating server socket: java.net.BindException: Address
>   already in use

This exception means that the port number the socket is trying to bind to (the port number your socket is trying to use in the local-end of the connection) is already in use by some other program. To fix it, you either need to find out what other software is using the port and see if you can safely change it, or change the port your program is using.

Edit: It might be worth trying to look for rarely used port(s), to lessen the chance of using yet another port that is known to be used by some common software, [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) Wikipedias list of typical TCP and UDP ports in use by common programs and services.

Comment: Thanks and the link - really appreciate it!  I have just updated my question.  There is one thing I am still not sure about. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I'll need some additional information for this: are both the collect- and server-class opening a ServerSocket using same port? If they are, they both can't use the same port at the same time, only one socket at a time can use the same port (doesn't matter if the sockets are opened by the same or different program). The earlier socket needs to be closed before you can open a new socket using the same port. It would probably help if you could provide a simple example of how the classes work (just the socket-usage parts)

Comment: hey! Yes, that will be really great!  We have been working on this for awhile now.  Let me update the question by including additional information right now.  Thanks!!

Comment: Hey esaj, I have updated the additional information.  Please see if this is enough, I took out as much unrelated information as possible. Thanks!

Comment: How is the clientSend -method "stuck"? The execution just stops and the software freezes? Do you have a debugger available or do you know in what line it is stuck?

Comment: Hi! The way I was trying to debug is to System.out.println("I am at the end of [the procedure in question]") then look at the java console. For example, the console displayed: I am at the end of ComputeGridValue() \n I am at the end of clientSend.  But then it stopped (suppose to have "I am at the end of construct Server for collect").  And also I displayed on the canvas a line "Submitting data to server..." and it clears if the procedure is successful (or display "failed") but that line just linger there without any response from the server - so I guess, the server is not even created!Thanks!

Comment: If you still get the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" -message when starting your server, the server is not started. Instead, your client connects to whatever is listening to that port and tries to send the data to that. Why it gets stuck, I really can't tell...